# Threading error when importing hello world programm for Teseo-LIV3F & Nucelo-f401re

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, stm32, mbed

I am trying to run the hello world program to obtain the lat and long coordinates of my position using the program linked here —> https://os.mbed.com/components/X-NUCLEO-GNSS1A1/

I am using the Nucleo-f401re board and have the X-NUCLEO-GNSS1A1 shielded on top with the antenna.
The program compiles and runs perfect in the Mbed online compiler, but when I export to Mbed studio or keil. I receive the below shown error message when running the program. The program does, however, compile ok.

```
++ MbedOS Error Info ++
Error Status: 0x80010132 Code: 306 Module: 1
Error Message: Thread: 0x0, Parameter error
Location: 0x800EDF1
Error Value: 0x0
Current Thread: main Id: 0x20003B28 Entry: 0x800AAB9 StackSize: 0x1000 StackMem: 0x20002620 SP: 0x20017F4C
For more info, visit: https://mbed.com/s/error?error=0x80010132&tgt=NUCLEO_F401RE
-- MbedOS Error Info --
```

[image: enter link description here]

I have googled this error message and the following was obtained…

[image: enter link description here]

I'm not sure what action to take from here as i don't really understand the problem. If someone could shed any light i would greatly appreciate it.

I don't know which line of code is causing the error and im not sure it actually is a line of code that is causing the error. Maybe out of date libs or something.

This is the Main code -

```
int main() {
  Thread consoleThread;
  Thread cmdThread;

  consoleThread.set_priority(osPriorityIdle);
  cmdThread.set_priority(osPriorityIdle);

  serialDebug.format(8, Serial::None, 1);
  serialDebug.baud(115200);
  consoleThread.start(_ConsoleRxHandler);

  gnss.reset();
  gnss.onLocationUpdate(locationHandler);
  TESEO_APP_LOG_INFO("Success to new GNSS.\r\n");

  _AppShowCmd();
  cmdThread.start(_ExecAppCmd);

  while(1) {
    ThisThread::yield();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please include the error stacktrace, and the code causing the error, as text in your question. That way it shows in search and other users seeking to help you can simply copy it to their convenience.

Comment: Hi I have copied in the text of the error shown in the photo. There is no specific line of code to show as like I said the code runs fine in the online compiler and also compiles fine in Mbed studio. I only receive the error when running in the serial comms window in Mbed studio.

Comment: The diagnostic indicates that there is a "parameter error" in the main thread.  This thread runs before the scheduler starts and is suspended thereafter.  You might step through your start-up code in the debugger to determine what call is failing and what its parameters are.  At the very least perhaps post the code in `main()`.  Also look at your link map to determine what is at or around  `0x800EDF0`.  I am not familiar with mbed diagnostics, but `StackSize: 0x1000 StackMem: 0x20002620 SP: 0x20017F4C` would suggest to me that the stack pointer is no longer in the allocated stack space!

Comment: Hi Clifford, thanks for your edit and helpful suggestions I will look into them. I have also posted the main code as you suggested.